# Rewrite HTTP to HTTPS while deleting www

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I need all http://www.domain.com to be redirected to https://domain.com

This is the code that allows me to redirect all http to https:

```
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

And it works perfecty, this is the code that was redirecting all www to @ :

```
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But I can't merge them together, that is, to have both http redirected to https, and www to @ at the same time. How can this be achieved?

Comment: What do you mean by can't merge them? Surely you just have to wait for a maximum of two redirects before the desired result?